# Vue - Accessing slot children classes in render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx

I have a component that has a default slot, and in a render function i'm trying to wrap each item in the `slot` inside a div in order to control the layout better.

I need to grab one of the slot elements classes (if it exists) to add it to the wrapper element, but the `VNode` element does not have `elm` or `$el` available when the function is running, it's still `undefined`.

**Parent component template:**

```
<Parent>
   <span>child 1</span>
   <p class="push">child 2</p>
   <Child>child 3</Child>
</Parent>
```

**Expected rendered result:**

```
<Parent>
   <Wrapper>
      <span>child 1</span>
   </Wrapper>
   <Wrapper class="push">
      <p>child 2</p>
   </Wrapper>
   <Wrapper>
      <Child>child 3</Child>
   </Wrapper>
</Parent>
```

For now, this is my render function which properly wraps each element, but **it's not finding the class in the slot children**, it seems like it's not accessible !

```
render(createElement) {
    const childs = [];
    this.$slots.default.forEach(item => {
      if (item.tag) {
        console.log(item.elm, item.componentInstance); // both returns undefined
        childs.push(createElement("Wrapper", [item]));
      }
    });

    return createElement(this.tag, { class: this.classes }, childs);
  }
```

**So, how can I access the slot element's classes in the render function ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `data.staticClass` attribute:

```js
Vue.component("Child", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot />
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component("Wrapper", {
  template: `
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
  `
})
Vue.component("Parent", {
  data() {
    return {
      tag: 'div'
    }
  },
  render(createElement) {
    const children = [];
    this.$slots.default.forEach(item => {
      if (item.tag) {
        let wrapperClasses = null
        if (item?.data?.staticClass) {
          // extracting the static class
          wrapperClasses = item.data.staticClass

          // "null"ing the static class on the passed in item
          item.data.staticClass = null
        }
        children.push(createElement(
          "Wrapper", {
            class: wrapperClasses
          }, [item]
        ));
      }
    });
    return createElement(this.tag, children);
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
    <div>
      <Parent>
        <span class="pull">child 1</span>
        <p class="push">child 2</p>
        <Child>child 3</Child>
      </Parent>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
.push {
  color: red;
}

.pull {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

- You can check the classes in the console.